# WCF bindings mismatch

Tags: c#, wcf

I am brand new to WCF and I am running into an issue.  I have a solution with a WCF service and a Unit Test.  I can build the solution but when I go to -> Add Service Reference -> Discover and click on my service I get this exception

> There was an error downloading `'http://localhost/MyService.svc/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'`.
>   The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
>   Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: `'http://localhost/MyService.svc'`.
>   Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service `http://localhost/MyService.svc`.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.
>   The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type.
>   If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

I have read numerous things but nothing is working, any ideas?

Here is my config

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Services.Biceps.BicepsItemService.ServiceBehavior" name="BicepsItemService">
        <endpoint address="basic" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Services.Biceps.IItemService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
     <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Services.Biceps.BicepsItemService.ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Did you remove the mex endpoint?
Have you changed the default configuration??
Post your app/web.config so we can verify your settings.

Comment: When you click discover, what is the url the application "Discovers"?

Comment: Also try surfing to the URL: http://localhost/MyService.svc/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/ if there is an internal server error you will get more information about it. If that is the case post it here as well.

Comment: http://localhost:56972/BicepsService.svc

Comment: I see, you probably changed the url of your service at some point, check your .svc markup file if it has errors also check your filenames if they match the BicepsSerivce url.

Comment: Try surfing in the browser to localhost:56972/BicepsService.svc you will most likely get a more explaining error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I had the wrong type listed as the *Name* in the Service attribute in my config, I had the Interface instead of the Implementation